# minimum value of $\cos(A-B)+\cos(B-C) +\cos(C-A)$ is $-3/2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How to prove that the minimum value of $\cos(A-B)+\cos(B-C) +\cos(C-A)$ is $-3/2$

Comment: Can $A,B,C$ be anything, or just angles of a triangle? (Or neither?)  What are the restrictions (if any) on $A,B,C$?

Comment: any kind of angles

Comment: Let $f(x,y):=\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(x+y)$ (use substitutions $x=A-B$ and $y=B-C$ and $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$). We are looking for its minimum value, so look for zeroes of its differential.

Comment: If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are separated by $120^\circ$ (modulo $360^\circ$), then the cosine of the difference of any two of them is $-1/2$, so the minimum is $\leq -3/2$.

Comment: @John : No matter what angles $A$, $B$, and $C$ are, the three angles $A-B$, $B-C$, and $C-A$ satisfy the constraint that their sum is $0$.  So we have two degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with $F=\cos(a-b)+\cos(b-c)+\cos(c-a)$ expand the cosines via the addition formula for cosine, and get
$$\cos a \cos b + \cos b \cos c + \cos c \cos a \\
+\sin a \sin b + \sin b \sin c + \sin c \sin a.$$
Then after applying $(u+v+w)^2-u^2-v^2-w^2=2uv+2vw+2wu,$ the double  $2F$ of our objective function may be seen to be 
$$2F=(\cos a+\cos b +\cos c)^2+(\sin a +\sin b + \sin c)^2-3.$$
Note we have combined the terms e.g. $-\cos^2 a -\sin^2 a=-1$ to obtain the final $-3.$
Thus $2F \ge -3$ i.e. $F \ge -3/2.$ Since there are values of $a,b,c$ which achieve $F=-3/2$ this finishes a proof.

Comment: @mathslover Is this last comment really just a separate question, or are you saying it would be another way to show the claim of the question in your posted question above? [I think the only thing I left out of the above answer was the values of $a,b,c$ which would give $-3/2$, for example $0,2\pi/3,4\pi/3$]

Comment: will it only take values 0 and 2pi/3 .4pi/3,,of these types..?? the above comment is the extension of this question..

Comment: @mathslover One can add any constant $c$ to all three angles and get other examples, i.e. $(0+c,2\pi/3+c,4\pi/3+c)$ are points for which the objective function $F$ is $-3/2$. I think these are the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

As Berci suggested ,$x=A-B,y=B-C \to f=\cos {x} +\cos{y}+cos{(x+y)}$

$f=2\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}} \cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}+2\left(\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\right)^2-1 \ge 2\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}+2\left(\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\right)^2-1 =2\left(\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2-\dfrac{3}{2} \ge -\dfrac{3}{2}$

first " $\ge$ " : $\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}<0,x=y$

second " $\ge$ " : $\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$

so the "=" will hold  when $x=y= \dfrac{2\pi}{3}(or \dfrac{4\pi}{3})+2k\pi $

Comment: There is also equality when $x=y=\frac{4\pi}{3}.$

Comment: @ya, you are right. edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If $\displaystyle2x+2y+2z=n\pi,$

$$F=\cos2x+\cos2y+\cos2z=2\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)+2\cos^2z-1$$

As $\displaystyle x+y=n\pi-y, \cos(x+y)=(-1)^n\cos z$
$$\implies2\cos^2z\pm2\cos z\cos(x-y)-(1+F)=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\cos z$

So, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$\implies (2\cos(x-y))^2\ge 4.\cdot2(-1-F)\iff 2F\ge-2-2\cos^2(x-y)\ge-3 $$

The equality occurs if $\cos^2(x-y)=1\implies \cos2(x-y)=2\cos^2(x-y)-1=1\iff 2(x-y)=2m\pi$ where $m$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

This [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419019/minimum-value-of-cos-x-cos-y-cosx-y/4176967#4176967) can be used (substituting $(A-B)$ as $X$, $(B-C)$ as $Y$)