# How to solve this inequality.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be the angles of a triangle. Show that 
$\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}.\sin\frac{\beta}{2}.\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}<{\frac{1}{4}}$

Comment: To understand question right... Is that sin * sin * sin?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2=\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2-\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2$$

and $$\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2=\cos\frac{\pi-\gamma}2=\sin\frac\gamma2$$

Now use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639890/minimum-value-of-cosa-b-cosb-c-cosc-a-is-3-2/640059#640059) method

Answer (score 1):

As $0<\dfrac\alpha2<\dfrac\pi2,\sin\dfrac\alpha2>0$ etc.,

using A.M. $\ge$ G.M

$$\frac{\sin\dfrac\alpha2+\sin\dfrac\beta2+\sin\dfrac\gamma2}3\ge\sqrt[3]{\sin\dfrac\alpha2\cdot\sin\dfrac\beta2\cdot\sin\dfrac\gamma2} $$

Again as sine is [concave](http://planetmath.org/concavityofsinefunction) in $[0,\pi]$ using [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form)

$$\frac{\sin\dfrac\alpha2+\sin\dfrac\beta2+\sin\dfrac\gamma2}3\le\sin\left(\dfrac{\dfrac\alpha2+\dfrac\beta2+\dfrac\gamma2}3\right)=\sin\frac\pi6=\frac12$$