# Trigonometric Inequality $\sin{A}+\sin{B}-\cos{C}\le\frac32$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

To prove
$$\sin{A}+\sin{B}-\cos{C}\le\frac32$$
Given $A+B+C=\pi$ and $A,B,C>0$

I have managed to convert LHS to $$1-4\cos{\frac C2}\sin{\frac{A+C-B}2}\cos{\frac{A-B-C}2}$$ but that clearly isn't very helpful

One other conversion was $$\sin A+\sin B+\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$ but not sure how to proceed.

Any **hints** will be appreciated

Comment: Duplicate  found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csin%7BA%7D%2B%5Csin%7BB%7D-%5Ccos%7BC%7D%5Cle%5Cfrac32%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [In $ \triangle ABC$ show that $ 1 \lt \cos A + \cos B + \cos C \le \frac 32$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949530/in-triangle-abc-show-that-1-lt-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-le-frac-32) OR [$ \cos {A} \cos {B} \cos {C} \leq \frac{1}{8} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952893/cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-leq-frac18)

Let $y=\sin A+\sin B-\cos C=2\cos\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2-2\cos^2\dfrac C2+1$

$$\iff2\cos^2\dfrac C2-2\cos\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+y-1=0$$

As $\cos\dfrac C2$ is real,the discriminant $\ge0$

$$4\cos^2\dfrac{A-B}2-8(y-1)\ge0\iff8y\le8+4\cos^2\dfrac{A-B}2\le8+4$$

Comment: So, the equality occurs if $C=\dfrac{2\pi}3, A=B=?$

Comment: $\pi/6$, how did you get $2\pi/3$ though?

Comment: @AFalseName, For the equality, $$\cos^2\dfrac{A-B}2=?$$

Comment: =1 implying A=B, But how C = $2\pi/3$

Comment: oh, did you solve the first eq by plugging C = ($\pi-2A$)

Comment: @AFalseName, If $A=B,y=\dfrac32$  $$0=2\cos^2\dfrac C2-2\cos\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+y-1=?$$

Comment: Yep, Got it. thank you

Comment: Note that you answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647141.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks. I forgot the exact match. I've already linked with some related ones in the post itself.