# How prove this inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x^2+2016}}\le\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, summation, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given  $x,y,z$ are positive real number satisfy $xy+yz+xz=2016$. Prove that $$\sqrt{\dfrac{yz}{x^2+2016}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{xy}{z^2+2016}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{xz}{y^2+2016}}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$

---

I tried

$\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x^2+2016}}=\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x^2+xy+yz+xz}}=\sqrt{\frac{yz}{\left(x+y\right)\left(x+z\right)}}$

And by C-S $\sqrt{\left(x+y\right)\left(x+z\right)}\ge x+\sqrt{yz}$

i can't continues. Help me !

Comment: sorry, i fixed.

Comment: Suggest a fix in title also...

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: i would square the whole Thing and then apply $$AM-GM$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM 
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{z^2+2016}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{z^2+xy+xz+yz}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{xy}{(x+z)(y+z)}}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{y}{y+z}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{z}{z+x}\right)=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is something called the *Purkiss Principle* which would imply that in this case the maximum of $f$ is achieved when $x=y=z=\sqrt{2016/3}$. Thus, $$f(\sqrt{2016/3},\sqrt{2016/3},\sqrt{2016/3}) = 3/2.$$

Comment: i don't know about your answer, can you post new method ?

Comment: There was an article ([link](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Waterhouse378-387.pdf)) published in the 80's in the MAA Monthly discussing Purkiss Principle. I haven't read it years but think it's applicable to the question.

Comment: For the sake of keep your answer self-contained, you should include the statement of the Purkiss Principle here.