Prove that $\cos A + \cos B +\cos C \le \frac{3}{2} $ using Jensen's Inequality where $A,B,C$ are angles of a triangle
I came across this question in an exercise related to Jensen's Inequality, but I know that the function $ f(x) = \cos x$ changes its concavity after $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So I was not able to prove this result for an obtuse-angled triangle. So I want to know how this question can be solved using Jensen's Inequality. I was able to solve this question using a different approach here:-
Let,                                                                                                $\cos(A) + \cos(B) + \cos(C) = k.$
On factorizing $ \cos A + \cos B $  and applying 2 times angle formula for $\cos C$, we get
$$ 2\cos \left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right) + 2\cos^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)-1 = k.$$
As $A+B = \pi - C$, we get:-
$$2\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right) + 2\cos^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)-1.$$
On changing $2\cos^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$ into $\sin$ and simplifying, we get a quadratic in $\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$, Letting $\sin \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$ as $t$, we get:-
$$t^2 - \left(2\cos \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\right)t + (k-1) = 0.$$
For this to have real roots, its discriminant must be greater than zero, so:
$$ 2k - 2 \le \cos^2 \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right).$$
Since maximum value of $\cos^2 \left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$ is $1$, we get a maximum value of $k = \frac{3}{2}$.

The inequality fails for obtuse-angled triangles. For example, $\lim_{x\to0^+}(2\cos x+\cos(\pi-2x))=1$.

@J.G. Oops, I wrote the wrong inequality sign..I have edited  it now..Thanks

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949530/42969

You can even do it with vectors.

@MartinR But none of those linked solutions show "how this question can be solved using Jensen's Inequality".

I'm assuming you did the case when all angles are acute, as that's standard Jensens and you mentioned checking concavity. To continue in the spirit of your solution for the obtuse case:
WLOG let $ C \geq \frac{\pi}{2}$, so $ \cos C \leq 0$.
By Jensen's, since $A, B \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$,
$$ \cos A + \cos B \leq 2 \cos \frac{ A+B}{2}.$$
Let $ x = \frac{A+B}{2}$, then we want to maximize
$$\cos A + \cos B + \cos C \leq 2 \cos x - \cos 2x = 1 + 2 \cos x - 2\cos^2 x .$$
Let $ y = \cos x$, then we want to maximize
$$ 1 + 2y  - 2y^2 = -2(y - \frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{2}.  $$
Hence, naively $\frac{3}{2}$ is still an upper bound.
Note: Because $ \frac{A+B}{2} \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, the domain of $y$ is restricted to $ [ \frac{ \sqrt{2}}{2}, 1 ]$, which gives a maximum of $\sqrt{2} $ when $ y = \frac{ \sqrt{2}}{2}$ in this obtuse case.

Thanks A lot, This was the solution I was looking for..

Hint:
Use the identity $$\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)\\=1+4\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$ The angles are now less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Let $f(x)=\log(\sin(x))$. $f$ is a concave function for $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, as $$f''(x)=-1-\frac{1}{\tan(x)^2}$$
We may now use Jensen to arrive at $$\frac{1}{3}\sum_{\sigma} \log\left (\sin\left (\frac{A}{2}\right)\right)\leq\sum_\sigma\log\left (\sin\left (\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{A+B+C}{2}\right)\right)=\log\left (\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ We then get $$\sin\left(\frac{A}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{8}$$ and so the claim follows.

You sure? In doing so you would get $\sin^2$ first, which is neither concave nor convex on $(0,\pi/2)$.

@Diger, got your point, Thank you!

You could have also used $$\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(c) \leq \left(\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{3}\right)^3 \leq \sin((a+b+c)/3)^3 = \sin(\pi/6)^3 =1/8$$
by AM-GM.
