# Show that $\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)+\sin^2(z) \le9/4$ where $x, y, z$ are angles of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> Let $x, y, z$ are angles of a triangle then
>   $$\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)+\sin^2(z) \le \frac{9}{4}.$$

I've tried to use the Jensen's inequality, but it can't help with $\sin^2(x)$...

Comment: Note that $\sin^2(t)=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}.$
Hence your inequality is equivalent to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100551/prove-that-cos2a-cos2b-cos2c-geq-frac32-for-angles-of-a-tr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $\cos(2a) + \cos(2b) + \cos(2c) \geq -\frac{3}{2}$ for angles of a triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100551/prove-that-cos2a-cos2b-cos2c-geq-frac32-for-angles-of-a-tr)

Answer (score 3):

By multiplying both sides by $4R^2$ we get $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq 9R^2$. This clearly holds since

$$OH^2 = 9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq 0, $$
see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334039/distance-between-orthocenter-and-circumcenter). A self-contained explanation might proceed as follows:
[image]

Assume that $A,B,C$ lie on some circle centered at $O$, with $B,C,O$ being fixed and $A$ being free to move on the (major, or minor) $BC$-arc. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. It is straightforward to notice that $AB^2+AC^2$ only depends on $AM^2$, hence it is maximized when $A$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$. It also follows that among the triangles with the same circumradius, the equilateral triangles (and they only) maximize the sum of the squared side lengths, so $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq 9R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

By the standard notation we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{4S^2}{b^2c^2}\leq\frac{9}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)\leq9a^2b^2c^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6-a^4b^2-a^4c^2+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$ which is Schur.

Done!

I used $$S_{\Delta ABC}=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4},$$
where $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$

Comment: What are summations evaluated over?

Comment: I explained it. See please better. $\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4.$

Comment: Ah, so cyclic permutations of the symbols a, b, c, ... Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If $S=\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C$

Using [Prove that $\cos (A + B)\cos (A - B) = {\cos ^2}A - {\sin ^2}B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345703/prove-that-cos-a-b-cos-a-b-cos-2a-sin-2b),

$S=1-(\cos^2A-\sin^2B)+1-\cos^2C=2-\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)-\cos^2C$
$=2+\cos C\cos(A-B)-\cos^2C$

$$\cos^2C-\cos C\cos(A-B)+S-2=0$$

which is a Quadratic Equation in $\cos C$ which is definitely real,

so the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$\cos^2(A-B)-4(S-2)\ge0\iff4S\le8+\cos^2(A-B)\le8+1$$

The equality occurs if

$\cos^2(A-B)=1\iff\sin(A-B)=0\iff A-B=0$ as $0<A,B<\pi$

$\implies\cos C=\dfrac{\cos(A-B)}2=\dfrac12\implies C=\dfrac\pi3$

and $A=B=\dfrac{A+B}2=\dfrac{\pi-C}2=?$

$\implies A=B=C$

Comment: See also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639890/minimum-value-of-cosa-b-cosb-c-cosc-a-is-3-2/640059#640059