# Solve using complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\cos(A-B) + \cos(B-C) + \cos(C-A) = \frac{-3}{2}$ 
We need to prove that $\cos A + \cos B + \cos C = \sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 0$

I was wondering if it's possible to prove this result by showing that the real and imaginary parts of $z = \cos A + \cos B + \cos C$ are equal to zero, somehow invoking Vieta's or De Moivre's theorem if required. I tried, starting with $\cos(B-C)$ and other cyclic terms but couldn't really get anywhere.

Any other method is also appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are $$A,B,C$$?

Comment: A, B, and C are just any three angles which satisfy the given condition

Comment: Is their sum $\pi$?

Comment: No their sum isn't π, no such restrictions

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639890/minimum-value-of-cosa-b-cosb-c-cosc-a-is-3-2  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397066/clarification-regarding-a-question

Comment: $$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)^2+(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)^2=?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u$, $v$, $w$ be $e^{iA}$, $e^{iB}$ and $e^{iC}$.
Then
$$(u+v+w)(u^{-1}+v^{-1}+w^{-1})
=2\cos(A-B)+2\cos(B-C)+2\cos(C-A)+3.$$
Your condition is equivalent to $(u+v+w)(u^{-1}+v^{-1}+w^{-1})=0$.
These brackets are complex conjugates, so $u+v+w=0$
and this means
$$(\cos A+\cos B+\cos C)+i(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C)=0.$$

Comment: Great man, thanks a lot. I liked that! Just a question, are there any other trigonometry problems you know of, which can be solved using complex numbers?

Comment: a good and short proof!

Comment: @user28968: Napoleon's theorem, for instance - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem